# The set of scalar function can be structured to a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I ask if it is possible to equip the set of scalar functions $\Bbb F^X$ between a set $X$ and a field $\Bbb F$ with a field structure. Indeed if $\Bbb F$ is a field and if $X$ is a set then for any $f,g\in\Bbb F^X$ I naturally thought to define an addition and multiplication in $\Bbb F^X$ through the following two identities
$$
(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)\\
(f\cdot g)(x):=f(x)\cdot g(x)
$$
for any $x\in X$ and this seems to me that make the set $\Bbb F^X$ to a field but I'd like to know from otherone if this is effectively true. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this does not work, because we will always have zero divisors when $|X| > 1$ (which cannot exist in a field).

Indeed, fix distinct elements $x\neq y$ in $X$. Define $f: X \to \mathbb{F}$ to be $1$ in $x$ and $0$ elsewhere. Similarly, define $g: X \to \mathbb{F}$ to be $1$ in $y$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then $fg = 0$ yet $f \neq 0$ and $g \neq 0$. Hence, $\mathbb{F}^X$ is never a field, unless $|X| = 1$ in which case $\mathbb{F}^X\cong \mathbb{F}.$

Comment: Okay, I understand. Anyway now I am asking to me if $X$ and $\Bbb F$ are topological spaces then the statement could be true if we consider the space $C\big(\Bbb F^X\big)$ of the continuous scalar functions. So what can you say about this particular case?

Comment: That's also only a ring. But that's good enough too.

Comment: @Berci Okay, but even the set $\Bbb F^X$ of **all** functions from $X$ to $\Bbb F$ with the operations above defined is a ring, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro This is even more general. If $R$ is a ring and $X$ is a set, then $R^X$ is a ring for the operations you defined.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Okay, all clear. Tanks to much for the answer!